# update a table in db2 row by row from .net

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, odbc, db2

I perform some actions on a table retrieved from a db2 database row by row in a C# project.
but when I try to update it using cursors row by row to the database using the following statement an exception is generated:

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "DECLARE crsr1 CURSOR FOR select * from " + tableName+" ;"
```

From my understanding of this, using cursors statements of db2 is not supported in .net languages. I am connected to the database using IBM DB2 ODBC drivers.

Is there is any way around using cursors , or if someone can tell whether there is something I am missing here.

I did a lot of searching on net , but not much is available on this problem.

this is the exception I got for the above statement --

```
"ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0104N  An unexpected token \"DECLARE CRSR1 CURSOR FOR select * from MYTA\" was found following \"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT\".  
Expected tokens may include:  \"<space>\".  SQLSTATE=42601\r\n"
```

any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably want to put that into a proc - you don't normally do a 'declare cursor..' outside of a Stored proc {unless you were debugging in the CLI or something}

Answer (score 0):

You should just put the "SELECT" part in the command text and use [ExecuteResultSet](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2CommandClassExecuteResultSetMethod2.html) method of DB2Command to return a resultset that wraps a scrollable updatable cursor.

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "select * from " + tableName+" ;"
using(var result = selectCommand.ExecuteResultSet(DB2ResultSetOptions.Updatable))
{
   while (result.Read())
   {
       //set value of 2nd column to 'Hello'
       result.SetString(1, "Hello");
   }
}
```